# Fire OnScroll Event using VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer

I have a webpage that has a secondary scrollbar embedded in the page that has a javascript function associated with the onscroll event. The onscroll event causes more rows to appear in the window. This is not a parent window scrollbar.

I cannot seem to get the event to fire using VBA and I cannot target the scrollbar either.

Here is the HTML with the JS event:

```
 <div id="divViewAreaTop" onscroll="GetMoreRecords(this)">
```

VBA Code:

```
 Dim scrollBar As Object
 Set scrollBar = IE.Document.getElementById("divViewAreaTop")
 scrollBar.FireEvent ("onscroll")
```

Here is the JavaScript Function that I am trying to fire:

```
var gettingMoreRecords = false;;
function GetMoreRecords(scrolldiv) {
if (AjaxBusy() || AjaxAsynchBusy()) return;

if (gettingMoreRecords) return;
var scrollwithin=40;
if (scrolldiv.scrollTop >= (scrolldiv.scrollHeight-scrolldiv.offsetHeight-scrollwithin))
{
    var which = EnvListTableId();
    var list = GetE(bdyId + which);
    var pg = GetE(bdyId + "hdnPageIdx");
    if (list && pg) {
        var idx = parseInt(pg.value);
        var total = parseInt(list.getAttribute("total"));
        var perpage = parseInt(list.getAttribute("perpage"));
        idx++;
        if ((idx*perpage) < total) {
            gettingMoreRecords = true;
            pg.value = idx;
            GetE("divListWait").style.display="block";
            var lastrow = LastRowPosition();
            AjaxReqAsynch("ManageEnvelopes.aspx?issortpage=1&action=refreshgrid&which=" + which + "&lastrow=" + lastrow + AjaxUrlParams(), GetMoreRecordsDone, GetMoreRecordsError);
        } else {
            GetE("divListWait").style.display="none";
        }
    }
} else {
    GetE("divListWait").style.display="none";
    }
}
```

I appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: The event name is "scroll", not "onscroll". (Though we're talking about IE, so I could be wrong.)

Comment: No dice. "Invalid Argument"... FireEvent ("onscroll") does not display an error, but does fire the JS.

Comment: :eyeroll: Hmm. Well I'd add some logging or something to make sure the event handler in the browser context is being called.

Comment: I think the issue is that I have to pass the parameter into the javascript function to get it to access the correct logic in the function.